# URL to check latest version of package on Nuget

Tags: powershell, nuget, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, nuget-package

Could someone please tell me the URL to check the latest version of specific package? I'm able to download the package by using https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/packagename but I want to check the version before downloading.

I don't want to use any visual studio extension or search box of Nuget.org.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With PowerShell you can use:

```
Find-Package <PackageName> | Select Version
```